# Web server not receiving POST from android app using Asynchttp - localhost

Tags: php, android, apache, post, localhost

I am trying to work on an android app to send a simple string to a webpage and have the webpage store the string. I recently installed BitnamiWAMP stack to use the PHP code and have been running my PHP through a local host. I followed a few tutorials and came across some examples of posting data using AsynchPost. My PHP code never returns a string. I don't know where to start to debug my app because my PHP code and Android app don't return any errors. Does anyone have any suggestions for what could be going wrong? Any help/advice would be appreciated. I am running my php script on an Apache 2.2 server and am sending data using android's emulator.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.post;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText value;
    private Button btn;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

                // out of range
                Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());      
            }


    } 

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            Log.v("parameters = ", params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/hello.php");
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", valueIWantToSend));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.v("Response = ", res);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            //return response.toString();
        }

    }
}
```

Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Enter Something Below:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=""
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.post.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

PHP code

```
<?php

//echo "hello";

if(isset($_POST['data'])) {

$message = $_POST["data"];

$filename = "androidmessages.txt";

ini_set("log_errors", 1);

ini_set("error_log", $filename);

error_log($message);
$file = fopen("test.txt", "w");
echo fwrite($file, $message);
fclose($file);

}
//echo $message;
//file_put_contents($filename, $message);

?>
```

Comment: Any errors (check your LogCat)?

Comment: @hichris123 No errors :( That's why I am confused.

Comment: Hmm... if you visit http://10.0.2.2:82/ on the emulator, does it display anything?

Comment: @hichris123 I will check. How do I display my address on the emulator?

Comment: Try just going to the browser and typing in `http://10.0.2.2:82`.

Comment: @hichris123 Ah right, It doesn't come up with anything. The android app must not be able to communicate with my local host option. I also just created a form to send data to my php script and it received it. It has to be something with the app.

Comment: @hichris123 localhost:82/ comes up with a response though. But I still cant communicate if I use that instead of 10.0.2.2

Comment: What do you mean with communicate? Can you read and display the response? That what the php script echoed? I see you have no e.printStackTrace() in your catch blocks. And no Log statements to see what is happening. Is the .txt file created on the server?

Comment: You should let postData return the response converted to string as result. And doInBackground return it again so you can show it in the onPostExecute toast. Or add Log statements everywhere.

Comment: @greenapps I added the printstacktraces and returned the response but unfortunately it caused my app to be stuck waiting on the loading bar. I am starting to think it may be a server issue on my local machine.

Comment: Please adapt your code here too. It looks as if you used the browser on your pc instead of a browser on the emulator. You have to use 10.0.2.2.

Comment: `waiting on the loading bar` ? Please tell what is the statement that `waits`.

Comment: @greenapps Done, I included my updated code. When I said waiting on the loading bar, I meant the app is stuck with the progress bar showing up without any progress being made.

Comment: Yes i understand but that is irrelevant. You should find the code line where execution is waiting. To do so add Log statements every where and report where it stucks. You have twice postData in doInBackground. Adapt the toast to display result.

Comment: First insure that ur emulator creates successful connection with localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has this question again - Fixed it. See updated code - for some reason file_put_contents wasn't working and the php never set the data. fwrite was a much better option, and ERROR_LOG is another way to write some contents to a file although it writes with a timestamp.